# MonoTouch Debug timing out quickly since upgrade?

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

Anyone else experiencing this since upgrading to the latest stable build a couple of days ago, where when debugging in the simulator after about 10 seconds after hitting a breakpoint it just ends the debugging session. I had never had this before, but now it is happening constantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you debugging a startup issue by any chance? iOS will kill your process if it hasn't started up in about 10 seconds (and it has always done that)

This is what I have in my code to workaround that (basically delay my startup code to the next 'turn'. You may need to something different)

```
// This method is invoked when the application has loaded its UI and its ready to run
        public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
                            delegate()
                            {
                                window.AddSubview(new MainView().View);
                                window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
                            });
            return true;
        }
```